# Where to put function which isn't clearly view / admin / model related?

Tags: django

If I have an app which stores and displays pizza and topping data, and I want to create a function which creates pizzas (using some complex logic), where is the best place to put it?

Should I create a separate file in the app called create_pizza.py, or is there some sort of best practice for adding this to the pizza model?

I feel like it should be in a separate file, as it will be used by other apps within my project.

Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 2):

A function that is concerned with acting on pizzas should go in the models.py file.

In particular, since it is about creating pizzas, it should probably be a method on a custom Manager class for pizzas. See [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/managers/) for more information.

Comment: Thanks. Let's say creating a pizza required some complex logic like checking best before date of ingredients, sorting toppings into some specific order, etc. Should this logic also be in the custom Manager? If so, is it in the same create function? Or should this logic be stored somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

you could/should put in a separate file since you are saying it isn't related to view/model/admin and is used by other apps too. it'll help you manage the project easily and easily understandable with less confusion.